# Multi functional Ajax - Multiple click with caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a few html partials being loaded through Ajax. These partials dont change much so i want to save them in a global variable e.g. **description**, **order information** etc..

I need to check whether the Ajax has been fired or not, if it hasn't then fire it and save the data, if it has, then use the cached data.

Finally, there can be multiple click options for these Ajax calls per page.

**Problem:**

The Ajax is firing but the data is not saving to the global variables for reuse.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 var description = sizeguide = '';
 // var sizeguide;

 $('#description').on('click', function() {
  ajaxLoad("partials/description.html", '.collection', description);
 });

 $('#sizeguide').on('click', function() {
  ajaxLoad("partials/size-guide.html", '.collection', sizeguide);
  console.log(sizeguide);
 });

 // AJAX Call
 function ajaxLoad(partials, location, element){

  console.log(partials + ' ' + location + ' ' + element);

  if(element == ''){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: partials,
    success: function(data) {
     element = data;
     $(location).empty().html(element);
    }
   });
  }

 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="description" name="description">Description</button>
<button id="sizeguide" name="sizeguide">Size Guide</button>


<div class="collection"></div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a flag to mark whether the ajax call has occurred or not?

Comment: @ThufirHawat Yes i have but since there are multiple buttons and multiple ajax partials, i cant really have one ajax marker

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? The browser has its own cache, it will use it for AJAX calls just like it does for real pages.